# What is the concept expressed with the word 'quasi' in day to day conversation?

Tags: standard-german

My German colleagues use the word 'quasi' . I wanted to use that word in my conversation but I am still confused about the usage of the word and grammar.

Comment: Sujatha could you please provide examples. This will make it easier to understand your question and explain it in the best way

Comment: Those are two questions and should be asked seperately (see https://german.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Please ask the question on *sogenannte* separately, thank you. To see the original for copy & pase just go to revision link at [*edited... ago*](https://german.stackexchange.com/posts/49506/revisions).

Comment: Quasi drückt schon mal kein Konzept aus. Es ist ein Wort, dessen Bedeutung man leicht nachschlagen kann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience this is in most cases just a filler word (expletive) and does not contribute to the meaning similar to *you know* in English.

The user wins some time to think about what should follow later in that sentence while speaking. As additional benefit the resulting sentence sounds more sophisticated, without much justification.

Comment: I can practically relate this in my office because my Product Owner almost uses this word in 2 out 3 sentences he speak. :-)

Comment: I can be that in some regions people say "quasi" in the same way as "ehm" or "genau". But the question was: "what is the concept". I think "ähm" is not a concept. I knew this word from my father. It wasn't a filler word. He was a poor gardener and a farmer son. He used  it when he explained to me the greek or latin name of flowers or mushroms. I've never heard this term again and I only used it once conducting a brass band:  it is really an official musical expression. But they were mocking about me  because they thought I was using it in the purpose as guidot mentioned. I really didn't know

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli: I'm unsure, what *concept* means in the original question. If it were meaning, the question would be off-topic anyway (covered by dictionary). My statement is, that *quasi* may simply mean nothing and considered that as a *concept*.

Comment: yes, I always used what concept of concept has someone when he says concept. the term concept has become the same kind of "abgefucked" as terms like "project" and "genau", "abolut" and " unbedingt" and "definitiv"!  in these cases I would absolutely underline what you're  quasi saying: "As additional benefit the resulting sentence sounds more sophisticated, without much justification." DEFINITELY! :)

Comment: Can't agree to that answer. _quasi_ says nothing more or less _effectively_ or _virtually_.
Example:
_Das ist quasi das Ergebnis der Diskussion._ //
_This is effectively the outcome of the discussion._

Answer (score 6):

**quasi means „sozusagen“, „gewissermassen“:**

https://www.wissen.de/synonym/sozusagen

English: in other words ...

This is an adverb describing e.g. the style how a tune may be played:

*quasy legato*

Answer (score 6):

Google translates it with "so to say", but i think in use I would rather translate it with "practically", in the usage of "those two things are practically the same". This would translate to "Diese zwei Dinge sind quasi (praktisch/sozusagen) dasselbe."

It is mostly used in cases when things are so similar that there is near to no difference between them "Meine Art zu laufen ist quasi rennen" - "My way of walking is 'practically' running" (because I'm a very fast walker).

Answer (score 4):

I'd translate "quasi" with "somehow", "in a manner of speaking".  Use of "quasi" implies an admission of "not literally so".

Comment: + "more or less"

Answer (score 2):

*quasi* is of latin origin and means "in a way, to some extent, quasi, allegedly". Used as a prefix in compounds it often means "nearly, almost" (similar to its spanish cognate *casi*). A good example for this is the word *Quasivertrag* (quasi-contract), a word which describes a legal relation of two parties which does not emerge of a mutual declaration of will (as a contract would need to), but comes with similar (or even equal) legal responsibilities as a contract.

However, since its meaning is rather weak, it is used by some people as a mere filling word. This stems from the fact, that *quasi* can be used in any case the speaker is not able or not willing to provide a more accurate description using a more telling adjective.